# How to plot specific rows and columns in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

My data frame consists of a list of 5 Crime types (plus their respective number of occurrencies) that were reported from Jan 2019 until Oct 2020 across 9 different regions in England.

I want to plot a graph with the crime occurrencies as the Y axis and the date as the X axis for each region **separately**, and not as faceted graphs.

To do that, I would have to single out the region I want to plot; I tried with

```
df$region == "Region_name"
```

But it didn't work out.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a sample of the data frame I am using:

```
structure(list(
Region = c("Yorkshire and The Humber", "East of England", 
  "East Midlands", "North East", "South East", "South East", "South East", 
  "East Midlands", "East Midlands", "London", "North West", "South West", 
  "East of England", "East Midlands", "East Midlands", "South East", 
  "Yorkshire and The Humber", "East of England", "East of England", 
  "East of England"), 
Date = structure(c(18109, 18383, 17928, 18293, 
  18414, 18536, 18170, 17987, 18322, 18140, 18383, 18475, 18231, 
  18048, 18353, 18322, 18475, 18170, 18109, 17897), class = "Date"), 
Crime = c("Violence and sexual offences", "Robbery", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Robbery", "Burglary", "Violence and sexual offences", "Robbery", 
    "Burglary", "Violence and sexual offences", "Robbery", "Robbery", 
    "Burglary", "Robbery", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Burglary", "Burglary", "Robbery", "Anti-social behaviour", 
    "Theft"), 
Crime_occurrencies = c(21001L, 177L, 6033L, 82L, 
    2635L, 24096L, 590L, 1536L, 7388L, 3205L, 163L, 981L, 232L, 
    5339L, 6367L, 3375L, 3238L, 257L, 10982L, 7906L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a line plot for each region like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(df,aes(x=Date,y=Crime_occurrencies,color=Region))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** Next code will create a list for each region:

```
#Unique regions
uni <- unique(df$Region)
#Plot func
myplot <- function(x)
{
  G <- ggplot(subset(df,Region==x),aes(x=Date,y=Crime_occurrencies,color=Crime))+
    geom_line()+
    geom_point()+
    ggtitle(x)
  G
}
#Apply
List <- lapply(uni, myplot)
```

Just type `List` on the console and all plots will appear.

Some output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather analyse each region separately though (i.e. I need a code that lets me select ONE region to plot), so that I can clearly see how each crime type occurrence changed over time. I will also add a linegraph of the unemployment rate changes over the same period of time to study any potential relationship with crime rate, but I need to do that for each region separately (avoiding the faceted graph option)

Comment: @Lactuca You want an individual plot for each region, but not facetted, right?

Comment: Yes exactly! And I would like to be able to select what to plot from the same data frame, so I don't have to create a vector for each region to plot it individually.

Comment: @Lactuca I can add a code to store all plots in a list, do you agree with that?

Comment: @Lactuca I have added an update, please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so quickly! I am very new to R so there's a few things I don't quite get from your code: what does function(x) do? Why are you using these parentheses "{"? Is this the only bit of code where I have to specify which region I want to plot?: (df,Region==x) Sorry if these are stupid questions!

Comment: @Lactuca It is fine, the curls were used to build a function which simplifies a lot of stuff. The part `(df,Region==x) ` is designed to catch each element of regions and then design the plot. Hope that was clear enough. Let me know if anything was not clear!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But I think I am way too inexperienced to understand it. I have no idea how function() works, I don't know where I have to specify which region I want to plot and I don't know what I'm supposed to put in place of the "x" in function() and ggtitle() (or if I have to type anything there at all). I tried naming them after a region but what comes out is a weird line graph that does not separate crime_occurrencies by crime types and that touches every point in the x axis, so I'm probably not using your code as it was supposed to be used. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @Lactuca The key is here `uni <- unique(df$Region)` in that value are saved all regions. So no need of writing them piece by piece. Then, the function makes the rest of the job. It is normal not understanding what is happening as you are a new learner :)

Comment: I got that bit, but how can I tell the function to show me the graph for (for example) North East? And how can I make sure that each line represents a different crime type? Yeah wrapping my head around all this has been a struggle haha

Comment: Add next code at the end `names(List) <- uni` and then type `List$` and tab and you will see all regions!

Comment: It doesn't show a graph whose line represents a different crime type though, it's only one single line that touches every point on the bottom of the X axis :s

Comment: @Lactuca Let me modify that!

Comment: @Lactuca I have added an update for you! Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thank you so much for putting up with my ignorance! I am not able to plot the unemployment rate graph on it though so I think I am gonna have to find another way to do what I originally planned. Thanks anyway, your code works perfectly!

Comment: @Lactuca Sorry for the confusion at the beginning. Nice it worked, as you are new R user, I use to teach special trainings. If you are interested please check my profile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2080848/duck?tab=profile) for useful details and contacts.